# In Python, write a program that asks the user to type in four numbers and puts all of them in a list called lst

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written a program that asks the user to type in four numbers like this:

```
a = input()
first = int(a) 
b = input() 
second = int(b) 
c = input() 
third = int(c) 
d = input() 
fourth = int(d)
```

I do not understand how can I put them in a list.

Answer (score 2):

You should improve your code a little bit:

```
first = int(input())
second = int(input())
third = int(input())
fourth = int(input())
lst = [first, second, third, fourth]
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you could use list-comprehension:

```
lst = [int (input ()) for time in range (4)]
```

This uses a simple `for` loop to execute `int (input ())` 4 times. Now you could just access the inputs by using `lst [0]`, `lst [1]`, `'lst [2]`, and `lst [3]`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can put your code in a code block by using an empty line and then indenting 4 spaces.

You can put your variables in a list like this:

```
list_variables = [first, second, third, fourth]
```

Answer (score 0):

option one :

```
lst = [first, second, third, fourth]
```

option two :

```
lst = []
lst.append(first)
lst.append(second)
lst.append(third)
lst.append(fourth)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more approach is to ask input numbers separated by space and then split them

```
numbers = input()
numbers_list = numbers.split(' ')
int_numbers_list = map(int, numbers_list)
```

Possible raise error if count of numbers not equal 4

```
while True:
    numbers = input()
    numbers_list = numbers.split(' ')
    if len(numbers_list) != 4:
        print('Enter numbers again')
        continue
    int_numbers_list = map(int, numbers_list)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ***1-liner*** but does not take care of the *4* input restriction (in case you need):

```
lst = list(map(int, input().split()))

'''
3 4 5 6
[3, 4, 5, 6]    
'''
```